# How to Rename a Database on a SQL Server Amazon RDS Instance?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

Attempts via SQL Server Management Studio and Transact SQL to rename a database hosted on a SQL Server Amazon RDS instance result in the following error.

> User does not have permission to alter database 'Morningstar', the
>   database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows
>   access checks.

Note that this is the Transact SQL statement that I tried.

```
ALTER DATABASE <OldName> Modify Name = <NewName>;
```

The best option that I have come up with so far is to restore a copy of the original database with the new name and then delete the original. See my [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15974926/81595) for details on how to do this.

There are at least the following disadvantages to this approach.

1. The export and import operations for a bacpac can take a long time.
2. Any applications or websites that perform writes to the database will need
   to be taken offline during the whole process.
3. There are manual steps involved which can result in errors.
4. The RDS instance will need to be large enough to host two copies of the database if you want to leave the original there as a rollback strategy until the new one is available.

Can anyone suggest an alternative approach that does not have these disadvantages?

**Update:** I am interested in renaming a SQL Server database that is hosted within an RDS Instance - not the RDS Instance.

Comment: Have you googled this error, checked aws forums and tried one on one aws support? Does the db exist, does your user have the right permissions? Can you try it with the root account? I know this is trivial with MySQL but haven't used mssql

Comment: I have not tried AWS support yet but will open a case. The database exists and the user is a member of the db_owner role which should be sufficient. I am using the RDS 'master user' which is I guess what you mean by 'root account'.

Comment: I have opened a case and did a screenshare with an AWS Support representative. We were not able to rename a database without getting the error that I detailed above. He is investigating further.

Comment: Goodluck! If you do find the answer you can post it here as an answer for others to benefit from :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

RDS has recently added a stored procedure to accomplish this:

```
EXEC rdsadmin.dbo.rds_modify_db_name N'<OldName>', N'<NewName>'
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.RenamingDB.html

Comment: Usually how long does it take for the name change to become effective?

Comment: @AnthonyKong it's immediate (if it succeeded).  You may need to refresh your database list in SSMS to see the change, though.

Answer (score 1):

AWS provided the following info in the case that I opened (paraphrased).

Although the master user is a member of the db_owner database role, a database rename requires a change in sys.sysdbreg which is in the master database. Membership in the db_owner role does not provide this permission.

The workaround that I described in my question is the method that they would recommend. I have asked for confirmation that there is no easier means of copying databases from and to RDS than the one that I described in my [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15974926/81595).

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect to the RDS MSSQL server
2. Open New Query window as master.
3. Copy and paste the below Query.

`EXEC rdsadmin.dbo.rds_modify_db_name N'OLD Database name', N'New Database Name'
GO`

5. Change the 'OLD database Name' as your existing database name.
6. Change the 'New Database Name' as a name you want to give to the database.

Source:
http://mytecksolution.blogspot.com/2017/09/rds-mssql-database-name-change-or-rename.html